# How can I make a VBA function work upon opening the workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I created a function in vba to determine if a row is visible.  The function returns 1 if visible and 0 if not visible.  The function looks like this:

```
Function IsRowVisible(MyRange As Range) As Integer

    If (MyRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
        IsRowVisible = 1
    Else
        IsRowVisible = 0
    End If

End Function
```

I then have a column in my workbook where I refer to this function in a formula such as:
=IsRowVisible(A1)

The formula returns #VALUE! until I run a macro that runs some other code or until I click the formula and hit Enter.  Then it works fine.

I would like it to work like a normal function in Excel where a value is returned when you open the workbook.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your desired outcome is the normal, expected behavior for a UDF in a workbook. It sounds like there is something else going on -- perhaps there is some other macro code tied to an event handler like Close, BeforeClose, Open, etc., that is altering the state of the workbook either when you close it, or when you first open it, but as your question is currently asked, there is not enough information to answer with much certainty.

Comment: For instance, if Row 1 is deleted *after* the function has been evaluated initially, the function will returns a #Value error since the range parameter no longer exists. If you examine the function, it might look like: `=IsRowVisible(#REF!)` .

Comment: The range being referred to exists and is not hidden.  For instance, in cell AL39 I have =IsRowVisible(A39).  In cell A39, I have someone's name.  When I click on cell AL39 and click the formula bar, and then hit return, the value in cell AL39 changes from #VALUE! to 1. That's the desired result.  It just needs to happen automatically without me having to signal it to calculate.  Imagine having this formula in 100 places.  Also calculations are set to Automatic.

Comment: show ALL of your code. otherwise, impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this improve things?:

```
Function IsRowVisible(MyRange As Range) As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    If (MyRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
        IsRowVisible = 1
    Else
        IsRowVisible = 0
    End If

End Function
```

This is probably a volatility issue.  Your function may only be re-calculating when the **value** in **A1** changes.

You may need to combine your function with a `SUBTOTAL()` function because `SUBTOTAL()` does recalculate when rows are hidden/unhidden.

Comment: I think this may have worked!!!! I will test this and mark as answered asap.  But for now, I have to run out of the office.  THanks!

Comment: That does, in fact, appear to be the trick.  Thank you again.

Comment: @JFrizz  Glad to help!